# How to close Phantomjs.exe in Windows Task Manager programmatically using Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am using [Phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) in my java application. However, i can't figure out how to close it. I tried both `close()` and `quit()` however, when I open `Windows Task Manager` i still can see the phantomjs.exe instances. How to close it ?

Comment: as a driver for selenium `driver = new  PhantomJSDriver(caps);`

Comment: Based on this [example](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/countdown.js), phantom.exit();  Phantomjs has no Java examples.  Java != Javascript

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `Process` reference to it,  the `destroy()` method in `Process` class will do the job.
However it will not work if phantomjs has child processes (see [explanation](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4770092))

You always may to call the following

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM phantomjs.exe")
```

Please note - this approach will make your application platform dependent.